# Nuget - Entity Framework Core issue with ASP.NET CORE - MVC)

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an application created in ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC. I just trying to connect with Db so I try to install the `Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore.SqlServer` package using Nuget package manager. I try to install all the available versions from 3.0 to 5.0.66, but I am getting following error.

I have double checked, I have the latest 2019 VS version and have installed .NET version 5, can someone please help what I am missing.

> NU1701: Package 'System.Collections 4.3.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
>
> NU1701: Package 'System.Collections.Concurrent 4.3.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
>
> NU1701: Package 'System.ComponentModel 4.3.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
>
> NU1701: Package 'System.Diagnostics.Debug 4.3.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
>
> NU1701: Package 'System.Diagnostics.Tools 4.3.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
>
> NU1701: Package 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing 4.3.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
>
> NU1701: Package 'System.Dynamic.Runtime 4.3.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
>
> NU1701: Package 'System.Globalization 4.3.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
>
> NU1701: Package 'System.IO 4.3.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
>
> NU1701: Package 'System.Linq 4.3.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
>
> NU1701: Package 'System.Linq.Expressions 4.3.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
>
> NU1701: Package 'System.Net.Primitives 4.3.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
>
> NU1701: Package 'System.ObjectModel 4.3.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
>
> NU1701: Package 'System.Reflection 4.3.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Comment: Try to right click the project and select the "Clean" option, and then choose the rebuild option to build the project. If it is still not working, can you share the application .csproj file content? I have tried to create an application and installed the related packages, it looks everything works well, the .csproj file [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYS87.png).

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your Visual Studio is up to date. There may be any minor update. If it is ok then check if `Visual Studio extension development` is installed.

Comment: Hi Nayeem,Thanks  for the reply , yes the vs is updated i have check no further upgrade so far. for  VS extension development i will check.

Comment: yeah.. pls check `vs extension development` is installed or not  and let me know if your are facing the same problem again... @YuvrajSingh